# What are the purpose of three bool value in PHPExcel reader?

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I'm using PHPExcel reader for read data from Exce file in my Yii2 application.
This is the code that I've used:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
        $fileName = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_vatout/') . $name;
        $inputFiles = fopen(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_vatout/') . $name, "r");
        try {
            $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($fileName);
            $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die('Error');
        }
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
        $colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
        $col = $colNumber - 1;
        $arrayData = [];

   $bool1 = NULL;            //first bool value
   $bool2 = NULL;            //second bool value
   $bool3 = NULL;            //third bool value
   for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
     $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, $bool1, $bool2, $bool3);
     if (!is_null($rowData[0][$col])) {
        $arrayData[] = array_map(function($values) {
           $tempArrayKey = [];
           foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
               $newKey = $key + 1;
               $tempArrayKey[] = $newKey . '_' . $value;
           }
           return $tempArrayKey;
     }, $rowData);
   }
  }
```

I used it following tutorial from some source. 
In line code `$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, $bool1, $bool2, $bool3);`, it has been set three boolean value. In my case I set them all as **NULL**.

**Anyone knows what are the purpose of the bool value actually?**

I've tried manytimes to read file, if I'm not wrong, the **second bool value** is set for read ***Excel Formula***.

But how about the others?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello there, i see you just begin beautiful journey into PHP language. Please don't forget to read doc's sometimes, something like this: http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_rangeToArray where all is explained one by one.

Comment: Oh, i forgot about one thing. You have to click "Create array from a range of cells" title to expand specification. Have fun friend!

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the [rangeToArray() method](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_rangeToArray)  is

```
/**
 * Create array from a range of cells
 *
 * @param string $pRange Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one cell (i.e. "A1")
 * @param mixed $nullValue Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist
 * @param boolean $calculateFormulas Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param boolean $formatData Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param boolean $returnCellRef False - Return a simple array of rows and columns indexed by number counting from zero
 *                               True - Return rows and columns indexed by their actual row and column IDs
 * @return array
 */
```

so

- `$bool1` - mixed `$nullValue`
  Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist (can be any datatype/value)
- `$bool2` - boolean `$calculateFormulas`
  Should formulas be calculated?
- `$bool3` - boolean `$formatData`
  Should formatting be applied to cell values?